# Why does non-reactive variable behave strange in Vue3?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, reactive

Here is the code

```
<template>
  <input type="button" value="click" @click="clickBtn"/>
  <div id="reactiveDiv">{{ reactiveVariable }}</div>
  <div id="noneReactiveDiv">{{ noneReactiveVariable }}</div>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref, nextTick } from "vue"

const reactiveVariable = ref('reactive')

let noneReactiveVariable = 'non reactive '

function clickBtn(){
  reactiveVariable.value = (new Date().getTime()).toString()
  noneReactiveVariable = (new Date().getTime()).toString()

  nextTick(()=>{
    console.log('next tick')
  })
}

</script>
```

I have two variables: reactiveVariable is reactive and noneReactiveVariable is not.

My question is:

1. When I click the button, both variables in template change. I think noneReactiveVariable should not be changed because it's defined without ref or reactive key words. My guess is that the reactive variable reactiveVariable's value change caused the template to update and caused the noneReactiveVariable in template change too. I don't know for sure.
2. if I change the template like this:

```
<template>
  <input type="button" value="click" @click="clickBtn"/>
  <div id="noneReactiveDiv">{{ noneReactiveVariable }}</div>
</template>
```

In this case, when I click the button, the noneReactiveVariable in template doesn't change. It seems ok now. But I have a nextTick in function clickBtn, I can see the log in console when I click the button which means the UI or template has updated. I think if the template has updated, why doesn't the noneReactiveVariable in template change just like before, the reactiveVariable change caused the noneReactiveVariable change?

Update:
I changed the code a little. Now noneReactiveVariable is changed in another function than reactiveVariable. But noneReactiveVariable is still being changed and update to DOM when button is clicked.

```
<template>
    <input type="button" value="click" @click="clickBtn"/>
    <div id="reactiveDiv">{{ reactiveVariable }}</div>
    <div id="noneReactiveDiv">{{ noneReactiveVariable }}</div>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref, nextTick, onMounted } from "vue"

const reactiveVariable = ref('reactive')

let noneReactiveVariable = 'non reactive '

onMounted(()=>{
    setInterval(()=>{
        noneReactiveVariable = (new Date().getTime()).toString()
    },1000)
})

function clickBtn(){
    reactiveVariable.value = (new Date().getTime()).toString()

    nextTick(()=>{
        console.log('next tick')
    })
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

So I just recently started with VueJs but as I understood it is that when you use a reactive variable when created with "ref" or "reactive", Vue internally tracks its dependencies, allowing it to automatically update the template when the reactive variable changes. Vue's reactivity system is smart enough to detect changes to reactive variables and trigger re-rendering of the template.

In your first piece of code, both reactiveVariable and noneReactiveVariable are rendered in the template. When reactiveVariable changes, Vue detects this change and updates the corresponding part of the template.

In your second piece of code, only noneReactiveVariable is rendered. When reactiveVariable changes, Vue doesn't have a dependency on noneReactiveVariable, so it doesn't trigger an update for noneReactiveVariable in the template.

In regards to your last question, i am not sure of `nextTick` function, but as far as I understand by reading the docs https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/event-loop-timers-and-nexttick. It's used to wait until the next DOM update cycle before executing the provided callback. Even though nextTick is called, it doesn't mean the template will immediately update. It will simply ensure that the callback is executed after the DOM has been updated in response to the current state changes. So in your case, the console.log('next tick') will be executed after the DOM has been updated, but since noneReactiveVariable is not a reactive dependency in your 2nd piece of code, it won't trigger a template update when it changes.

Hope this helps answer your questions.

Comment: About this: In your first piece of code, both reactiveVariable and noneReactiveVariable are rendered in the template. When reactiveVariable changes, Vue detects this change and updates the corresponding part of the template. noneReactiveVariable is not reactive So even if it's rendered with a reactive one, it should not be changed.

Comment: And you said, "the console.log('next tick') will be executed after the DOM has been updated,but noneReactiveVariable is not a reactive dependency in your 2nd piece of code, it won't trigger a template update when it changes." In the first piece of code, the Dom has been updated too. What's the different? If a non-reactive variable is with other variables that are reactive, it can be changed to reactive one?

Comment: So when you click the button, clickBtn method is called, and inside this method, you are updating both reactiveVariable and noneReactiveVariable. Even though noneReactiveVariable is not reactive, it's being accessed within the method where a reactive variable `reactiveVariable` is being updated. Therefore, Vue.js triggers a reactivity cycle, causing the template to re-render and displaying the updated value of noneReactiveVariable.

Comment: So if noneReactiveVariable is changed in different method, it won't be changed, right?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: I just did a test: 
onMounted(()=>{
    setInterval(()=>{
        noneReactiveVariable = (new Date().getTime()).toString()
    },1000)
})
function clickBtn(){
    reactiveVariable.value = (new Date().getTime()).toString()

    nextTick(()=>{
        console.log('next tick')
    })
}
<template>
    <input type="button" value="click" @click="clickBtn"/>
    <div id="reactiveDiv">{{ reactiveVariable }}</div>
    <div id="noneReactiveDiv">{{ noneReactiveVariable }}</div>
</template>
noneReactiveVariable is still changed when click the button.

Comment: Can you please post the piece of code as an edit of what you tried? It becomes a little easy to read the code.

Comment: Ok, I did an eidit.

Comment: Oh i see, so i guess noneReactiveVariable appears to be changing and updating in the DOM is because the setInterval function is continuously updating its value every second. But i believe that value of noneReactiveVariable changing, it's not causing a reactivity update in the template because it's not a reactive variable

Comment: Thank you Adi, I'm still confused. Lets see if others have some new thought.

Comment: @James The answer looks ok so far. nextTick is the shortest delay needed for the changes in a template to be applied in case they were, but it's not strictly tied to the updates, like in your example. It's Vue idiomatic way to wait a bit, like setTimeout 0, but it's generally faster